# Greater than or less than operators and versions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a MS SQL query that I am creating and I need to determine if a particular record falls into a "new" or "old" category based off of the version number.

There is a column 'VersionNum' and the old version is any version number from 2.75.99.99 and below while the new version is any version number from 2.76.00.00 and up. The data type for the column is varchar(20).

I was thinking about taking a subset of the string from X.XX and casting this as a decimal. Then once all versions are cast to a X.XX decimal I can determine old or new by performing a > or < in a case statement within the select.

Would this be the correct or idea way of going about deciding where the version numbers fall? Or is there some other method. I only ask because I would imagine that something similar to this is needed else where and this is not a unique situation.

EDIT: One additional issue. There are some versions that are not X.XX.XX.XX (2.76.00.00) and some are in the form: 8.00.00 and would be considered "Old" versions. This confuses the system a lot more than I once thought. I did get information that the 5 digit version (8.00.00) is considered old all the time. So whenever there are 5 digits, the version is old. So I am thinking I would perform a case statement similar to:

```
SELECT
    Old = CASE WHEN LEN(VersionNum) < 10 THEN 1
               WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(VersionNum,1,4) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) < 1.52
                    AND LEN(VersionNum) >= 10 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END,
    New = CASE WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(VersionNum,1,4) AS DECIMAL(5,3)) >= 1.52
                    AND LEN(VersionNum) >= 10 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
FROM
    VersionTable
```

Is my logic correct? Or am I missing something. The inequality in the lengths is very annoying.

Comment: Do you have the option of breaking the version number into 4 byte columns?  If you are going to cast it then Int32 should be big enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always express such a "number" as an integer, assuming it will always have only 4 parts:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(20);

SELECT @x = '2.76.99.99';

SELECT 
 v = PARSENAME(@x, 4) * 1000000
   + PARSENAME(@x, 3) * 10000
   + PARSENAME(@x, 2) * 100
   + PARSENAME(@x, 1);
```

Result:

```
2769999
```

So if you create a view or a computed column, you can compare using simple math instead of trying to do complicated parsing / conversion.

**EDIT** based on comment

If the table has some values that only have three octets, why not fix that?

```
UPDATE dbo.table SET col = col + '.00'
  WHERE LEN(x) < 10;
```

If you want to be more precise:

```
UPDATE dbo.table SET col = LTRIM(RTRIM(col)) + '.00'
  WHERE LEN(LTRIM(RTRTIM(x))) - LEN(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(x)), '.', '')) = 3;
```

Comment: +1 - Novel solution.  It should be noted that `PARSENAME` will only work with up to 4 values, though.

Comment: One issue I have. Now there are numbers that are X.XX.XX and some are X.X.XX.XXX This just confuses the matter even more. The 5 digit values are considered old while the 7 digit value (three build version digits) is considered new.

Comment: COALESCE( PARSENAME(@x, 4) , 0 )  * 1000000

Comment: @Blam that doesn't quite work. `2.76.99` becomes `27699` not `2769900`. I think a better answer is to fix the old data, once, rather than hack and kludge a query to suit it - especially given that no new data will be introduced in the old format.

Comment: @AaronBertrand OK I was not trying to take over your answer.  I gave it a +1 a while ago.  If 5 digit are old then would it not sort correctly?

Comment: @Blam I guess it depends on whether the new format came into being all at once or if it was gradual. Still I'll argue that fixing the old data is better.

Answer (score 1):

The real fix for this is to break out your version number into a series of `smallint`, `int`, or `bigint` fields depending on what ranges you need.  If you can't do this, then you could potentially make a lookup table for them but this is a much messier solution.

If you had, say:

```
CREATE TABLE Versions
(MajorVersion int,
 MinorVersion int,
 Subversion int,
 Build int)
```

Then you can compare the individual fields as needed.

Comment: +1 because I also agree that these things should be stored separately. Still the calculation to determine whether one version is greater than another is still a non-trivial expression.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers in the version strings are zero-padded on the left, then you can just use string compare:  "2.75.99.99" < "2.76.00.00".

This will work assuming that the format remains consistent across all the versions.

Comment: Except if you leave them as strings  then `'12.8.99' < '2.8.99'` will return `TRUE`...